# Emissão de nota não fiscal

Tags: php, javascript, erp

Boa tarde a todos. Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema web para minha loja e eu gostaria de saber como eu imprimo aquelas notas não fiscais que mostram os produtos com seus códigos de barra, preços, quantidades... Aquela nota que é impressa quando compramos algo. Preciso ter uma base de como mandar os itens do carrinho para a nota, e como faço para integrar com a impressora não-fiscal. Meu sistema é criado com PHP e JavaScript. Obrigado desde já.

EDIT: Esclarecendo melhor, eu quero saber uma forma de criar aquelas notas não fiscais que recebemos ao comprar algo. Quero uma forma de criar aquela notinha e adicionar os itens do carrinho nessa notinha e imprimir usando aquela impressora não fiscal.

Comment: Deveria ser reaberto, de cunho muito interesse e proveitoso.